# Dockerize .NET solution with 2 executable projects

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, docker-compose, dockerfile

I was asked to create a .net solution with a web api and a console program, then have this available with a docker-compose command that includes the full environment. The web api is using mongodb and easynetq. The console program references the web api project and also uses easynetq. I know Visual Studio can provide me a dockerfile for each project. How do I proceed after this? Do I combine the 2 dockerfiles into 1 at the solution level? Or can I continue with the 2 dockerfiles?

Dockerfile for console program

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet restore "./ConsoleProgram.csproj"
RUN dotnet publish "ConsoleProgram.csproj" -c Release -o out
FROM microsoft/dotnet:aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ConsoleProgram.dll"]
```

Dockerfile for webapi is identical as above, only names are changed

Docker compose at solution level

```
version: '3'

services:

mongo:
  image: mongo
  restart: always
  ports:
    - 27017:27017

webapi:
  build: ./webapi
  restart: always
  ports:
    - 5000:80
  environment:
    MongoDB__Host: mongo
  depends_on:
    - mongo

console:
  build: ./console
  restart: always
  depends_on:
    - webapi
```

After doing a docker compose on this I get the following errors:

> Skipping project "C:\WebApi\WebApi.csproj" because it was not found.
>   The referenced project '..\WebApi\WebApi.csproj' does not exist.
>   Service 'console' failed to build: The command 'cmd /S /C dotnet
>   publish "Console.csproj" -c Release -o out' returned a non-zero code:
>   1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right way. You should have *Dockerfile* for each projects (in root of the project folder), then one file *docker-compose.yaml* and many *docker-compose.override.yaml* if you need.

There are some gaps in Dockerfile.

1.Don't copy `COPY . ./` all files in ConsoleProgram image, first just copy csproj

```
COPY console/ConsoleProgram.csproj console/
```

2.After copy csproj file run `dotnet restore` to improve image building time

```
RUN dotnet restore console/ConsoleProgram.csproj
```

3.Then copy all other files and run `dotnet publish` (or `build`) with flag `--no-restore`

```
COPY console/ console/
RUN dotnet publish console/ConsoleProgram.csproj --no-restore -c Release -o /out
```

Here are some example how *Dockerfile* should look

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS publish
WORKDIR /src

COPY console/ConsoleProgram.csproj console/

RUN dotnet restore console/ConsoleProgram.csproj

COPY console/ console/

RUN dotnet publish console/ConsoleProgram.csproj --no-restore -c Release -o /app

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ConsoleProgram.dll"]
```

Something similar should be for WebAPI. Now look at your *docker-compose.yaml*. You should specify build context and image name

```
webapi:
  image: 'webapi'
  build: 
    context: .
    dockerfile: ./webapi/Dockerfile
  restart: always
  ports:
    - 5000:80
  environment:
    MongoDB__Host: mongo
  depends_on:
    - mongo

console:
  image: 'console'
  build: 
    context: .
    dockerfile: ./console/Dockerfile
  restart: always
  depends_on:
    - webapi
```

As I doesn't know your project structure you need to be careful with all paths to project in this answer